# Performance comparison: SQL query using in and like

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Which query runs faster?

Considering it returns 200 records and `authorname` is atleast 20 chars long and `authorname` is fulltext indexed

```
select * from quotestable 
where quotesauthor like (select Authorname from  Authortable where authorid =45)
```

.

```
select * from quotestable 
where quotesauthor in (select Authorname from  Authortable where authorid =45)
```

Comment: Why not just have a look at the execution plan for each?

Comment: Not part of the question but its possible the queries could generate different results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a question of "faster". They have different meanings.

The first query can only run if the subquery returns 0 or 1 records (and should normally use `TOP 1` to guarantee this). However, it can do wildcard matching on the results. The second query can run if the subquery returns any number of records, but will not do wildcard matching.

It sounds like what you should really have here is a JOIN:

```
SELECT q.* 
FROM quotestable q 
INNER JOIN AuthorTable a ON q.quotesauthor = a.authorname
WHERE a.authorid = 45
```

... assuming of course that `AuthorID` or `AuthorName` is unique in `AuthorTable`. This will also allow to use LIKE with wildcards for the matching condition, in the case where the quotesauthor field might not always be a direct match  with `AuthorTable.AuthorName`.

While I'm here, it's also strange to me that `AuthorName` would be full-text indexed. A traditional index, rather than fulltext, would be more helpful for this query. The only reason to use fulltext here is if you have full names like 'John Milton' in that field, and want to be able to do things like search on last name only or first name only. But even in that case, it seems like you'd be much better served by storing those as their own fields and removing the fulltext index. Fulltext indexes work best on longer fields, like descriptions or articles/posts.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same. One test equality, other test like expression...

try this for equality

```
select * from quotestable f1 
where exists 
(
select * from  Authortable f2
where f2.authorid =45 and f1.quotesauthor =f2.Authorname
)
```

try this for like

```
select * from quotestable f1 
where exists 
(
select * from  Authortable f2
where f2.authorid =45 and f1.quotesauthor like '%' + f2.Authorname + '%'
)
```